Question about definition of affine subspace

Definition. A subset $\mathcal{A}'$ of the affine space $(\mathcal{A},V,\varphi)$ is
called affine subspace if there exists a vectorial subspace $V'$ of
$V$ such that $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi'=\varphi\vert_{\mathcal{A}'
 \times \mathcal{A}'}) \subset V'$ and $(\mathcal{A}', V', \varphi')$ is
an affine space or if $\mathcal{A}' = \emptyset$.

My question is: Isn't condition $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi'=\varphi\vert_{\mathcal{A}'
 \times \mathcal{A}'}) \subset V'$ redundant? Because we know that if $(\mathcal{A}', V', \varphi')$ is an affine space, then for any $O \in \mathcal{A}'$ we have that $A \mapsto \varphi'_O(A) = \varphi'(O,A)$ is bijective, so surjective. And from this it results that $\varphi'$ is surjective, so $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi'=\varphi\vert_{\mathcal{A}'
 \times \mathcal{A}'}) = V'$.

It's arguably redundant, but I think if it weren't written it would be confusing to read the next part. (Also, should the restriction be to $\mathcal{A}'\times \mathcal{A}'$?)

@hunter yes it was $\mathcal{A}' \times \mathcal{A}'$. Sorry for typo

However I'm still confused...

This isn't different from what I said in the comment above, but I'm making it an answer since you asked for more clarification. I think this is an issue of mathematical writing style and not math. (For simplicity, I'm ignoring the little add-on at the end clarifying that the empty set is an affine subspace, and correcting some grammar -- is the definition translated from a non-English source?) The current definition is:

Definition. A subset $\mathcal{A}'$ of the affine space $(\mathcal{A},V,\varphi)$ is
called an affine subspace if there exists a vector subspace $V'$ of
$V$ such that $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi'=\varphi\vert_{\mathcal{A}'
 \times \mathcal{A}'}) \subset V'$ and $(\mathcal{A}', V', \varphi')$ is
an affine space.

If the writer had removed the first clause you are calling redundant, literally, we'd have

¿Definition A? A subset $\mathcal{A}'$ of the affine space $(\mathcal{A},V,\varphi)$ is
called an affine subspace if there exists a vector subspace $V'$ of
$V$ such that $(\mathcal{A}', V', \varphi')$ is
an affine space.

but this wouldn't parse because $\varphi'$ is not defined. So the author could instead write:

¿Definition B? A subset $\mathcal{A}'$ of the affine space $(\mathcal{A},V,\varphi)$ is
called an affine subspace if there exists a vector subspace $V'$ of
$V$ such that $(\mathcal{A}', V', \phi|_{\mathcal{A}' \times \mathcal{A}'})$ is
an affine space.

I think this is what you want. It isn't wrong, but I don't like the way it's written. We've defined an affine space to be a triple of a set, a vector space, and a map from that set ot the vector space, but a priori, $\phi|_{\mathcal{A}' \times \mathcal{A}'}$ lands in $V$, not $V'$. You can argue: "by writing it this way, I am asserting that in fact that map lands in $V'$", but it's not to everyone's taste.
An analogy with a more familiar area of math:

¿Definition of a Subgroup? If $(G, \cdot)$ is a group, a subset $H$ of $G$ is called a subgroup if $(H, \cdot)$ is a group.

I don't like this definition for defining what a subgroup is because it sweeps the actual issue into the notation -- the operator $\cdot$ must have the property that $H \cdot H = H$. I would prefer this property to be spelled out.

Oooh. Ok. I understand now. Definition B is what I had in mind, but now with your clarifications original definition have more sense.
